# selenium Unable to find elements on closed window when navigate to other page on IE11

Tags: selenium

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Driver/IEDriverServer.exe");
Map<String, By> objectMap = DataHelper.getObjectMap();
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("XXXXX");
driver.findElement(objectMap.get("processworld_username")).clear();
driver.findElement(objectMap.get("processworld_username")).sendKeys("XXX");
driver.findElement(objectMap.get("processworld_password")).clear();
driver.findElement(objectMap.get("processworld_password")).sendKeys("XXX");
driver.findElement(objectMap.get("processworld_sign_in_btn")).click();
driver.findElement(objectMap.get("patt_createproject_link")).click();
```

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to find elements on
>   closed window (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information) Command duration or timeout: 10 milliseconds Build info:
>   version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'
>   System info: host: 'PHMNL1-SQLXiAn', ip: '10.164.228.143', os.name:
>   'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_101' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver Capabilities
>   [{browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.enableFullPageScreenshot=true,
>   enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false,
>   ie.forceShellWindowsApi=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal,
>   ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout=3000, version=11,
>   platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false,
>   elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=,
>   requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer,
>   initialBrowserUrl=http://patttest.emersonprocess.com/main.asp?url=,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false,
>   enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
>   Session ID: 9a00ac20-b304-4ba5-9667-149392ceedc5
>   *** Element info: {Using=partial link text, value=Create Project} at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:647)

After `processworld_sign_in_btn` is clicked, the page will navigate to a new page, then the error appears, I've tried to set the protected mode for all zones , but it not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the same issue once. It was solved with a simple registry update. I hope that this solution helps you -

You need to check a key in the registry editor -  ***HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE***

In 64 bit system, you can find the same key in ***HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE***

The sub key **FEATURE_BFCACHE** may or may not be present. You have to create it if it is not present. Inside this key, create a **DWORD** value and name it **iexplore.exe** with the value **0**.